# What should I expect to see if md/linux RAID is properly compensating for a failing drive?

Tags: raid, software-raid, md

Does the `md` subsystem output any messages (to syslog/systemd-journal) to indicate that it's running in a degraded state (or anything else that might indicate that it has successfully reacted to a drive failure, as [hinted at here](https://serverfault.com/questions/335062/linux-software-raid-robustness))?

For example, I see lots of errors from `sd` indicating things like `Unrecovered read error` but I don't see anything like "retried successfully on alternate". Maybe no news is good news?

Back in the day, mirroring software/hardware would generate syslog entries that indicated when a device was degraded or otherwise required attention.  Does `md` not do that?

Background: the systems in question are already deployed and are being remotely monitored (via syslog/journald info, so no `mdadm` or any other interactive commands/access of any sort are available at this point).

Comment: `cat /proc/mdstat` is an essential starting point

Comment: Previously posted (and closed as "off topic") at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/980072/what-should-i-expect-to-see-if-md-linux-raid-is-properly-compensating-for-a-fail).

Comment: @roaima please see "no interactive commands/access of any sort are available".

Comment: I see that. I still say that it's an essential starting point, but not as an answer because of your restrictions. (I'm looking to see what other options you've got.)

Comment: Without interactive access, how to you expect to recover from a failure?  If a disk fails and is failed out of the array, then when you replace it you need to tell the `md` driver to add the replacement disk.

Comment: @StephenHarris Recovery is by dispatching a technician to the site.

Comment: @roaima that's the message that I was looking for (i was able to search for `Disk failure` and identify an issue).  If you make that an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up a quick test on a RAID 1 array built from two loop devices.

```
dd bs=1M count=100 if=/dev/zero >/tmp/0.img
cp /tmp/0.img /tmp/1.img
i0=$(losetup --show --find /tmp/0.img); echo $i0
i1=$(losetup --show --find /tmp/1.img); echo $i1
mdadm --create /dev/md99 --metadata default --level 1 --raid-devices 2 $i0 $i1
```

Setting one half faulty

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md99 --set-faulty $i1    # For me, $i1=/dev/loop1
```

gives me this from the kernel (amongst other related RAID1 messages)

```
Oct 6 17:36:10 pi kernel: [4087450.030438] md/raid1:md99: Disk failure on loop1, disabling device
Oct 6 17:36:10 pi kernel: [4087450.030438] md/raid1:md99: Operation continuing on 1 devices.
```